# How to automate a build for a Visual FoxPro project?

Tags: command-line, build, foxpro, visual-foxpro

I'm interested in figuring out how to automate a build from Visual FoxPro similar to how we can build .NET projects from the command line using [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wea2sca5(VS.90).aspx).

It seems that it is possible to [pass command line arguments to VFP.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bzb50fbk(VS.80).aspx) which may include the ability to specify some initial startup prg that runs however it is unclear how well starting up the IDE will work from non-interactive accounts such as the Network Service on Windows which is likely where an automated build would run.

Has anybody attempt this before or read about anybody attempting to script a VFP build like this? I would be grateful for any pointers that may lead me to a solution.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A simple solution is to create a program file that builds the application, and call VFP to execute that program.  You can also add any pre or post build commands to that program file.

Create a VFP configuration text file, called BUILD.FPW

```
SCREEN=OFF
COMMAND=DO C:\Project\BUILD.PRG
```

Then create C:\Project\BUILD.PRG

```
Modify Project C:\Project\MyProject Nowait
_vfp.Projects.Item(1).Build("C:\Project\myapp.exe", 3, .f., .f.)
If file("C:\Project\myapp.err")
    * Do something for build errors
Else
    * No errors
Endif
Quit
```

Finally, to build it

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual FoxPro 9\vfp9.exe -CBUILD.FPW
```

VFP will build it non-interactively.  It will log build errors to myapp.err.  If it builds successfully, no error file is created.

Comment: I think this is the answer I need but FoxPro was soooo long ago for me. When I do exactly what you say above I get: 1689 Cannot build without a main program. What is C:\Project...Project root or where all my prg files live or...???

Comment: @ GPGVM: the parameter for the `modify project` command is the full pathname of an existing project file, in this case `C:\Project\MyProject`; the extension '.pjx' is implied and may be omitted. If the path contains blanks then it must be enclosed in quote characters (e.g. `modify project 'c:/subdir/name containing blanks' nowait`).

Answer (score 3):

- [Experience in Automate VFP Project
  Build](http://weblogs.foxite.com/kkchan/archive/2007/08/28/4763.aspx)  (FinalBuilder Route)
- [Automated Build](http://vfpx.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Automated%20Build&referringTitle=Home)